# calculate number of non-missing counts in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like below:

```
Col1   F1    L1    F2    L2     F3    L3
A     Jon    Ro   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
B    Koss   Lon   Pet Gross    NaN   NaN
C      Lo   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
```

I want to get count of non-missing based on `F` and `L`:

```
Col1   F1    L1    F2    L2     F3    L3   Cnt
A     Jon    Ro   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     1
B    Koss   Lon   Pet Gross    NaN   NaN     2
C      Lo   Pho   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     1
```

I tried below's code but got wrong result since it considered `F` and `L` separate instead of based on their suffix:

```
df["Cnt"] = df[df.filter(regex = "F|L").columns.tolist()].apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)

Col1   F1    L1    F2    L2     F3    L3   Cnt
A     Jon    Ro   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     2
B    Koss   Lon   Pet Gross    NaN   NaN     4
C      Lo   Pho   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Cnt'] = (
    df.filter(regex="L|F") # select only L or F columns 
      .groupby(lambda col: col[-1], axis=1)  # group the columns by suffix (assuming it's just the last character)
      .agg(lambda g: g.notna().any(axis=1))  # for each i check if  Fi or Li are not NaNs
      .sum(axis=1) # count the not-NaN groups row-wise (i.e. all the True values)
)

>>> df

  Col1    F1   L1   F2     L2  F3  L3  Cnt
0    A   Jon   Ro  NaN    NaN NaN NaN    1
1    B  Koss  Lon  Pet  Gross NaN NaN    2
2    C    Lo  Pho  NaN    NaN NaN NaN    1
```

Comment: Great answer! Just change `all()` to `any()`

Comment: @PeterChen it's not clear from the description which one you want, but I've updated now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df["Cnt"] = df.notna().sum(axis=1)/2
```